# How do I create a DatePicker in swiftUI that only select years and I want this to be in prespecified range of years?

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, swiftui

Im trying to build an app that user requests an item that has numerous generations and he has to enter which year does he want ?.

- date picker is wrapped up in form so when its hit it doesnt act like numerous pickers and navigate to picker only screen instead it creates datepicker view within the list  is there a way to navigate to it or at least resize it to a smaller size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your custom year picker by using a simple `Picker` and passing it an array of `Int` as your years.

```
struct YearPicker: View {
    private let numberFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let nf = NumberFormatter()
        nf.usesGroupingSeparator = false
        return nf
    }()

    @State private var selectedYearIndex: Int
    private let years: [Int]

    init(start: Int, end: Int) {
        let years = Array(start...end)
        self._selectedYearIndex = State(initialValue: years.startIndex)
        self.years = years
    }

    func yearString(at index: Int) -> String {
        let selectedYear = years[index]
        return numberFormatter.string(for: selectedYear) ?? selectedYear.description
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Your birth year is \(yearString(at: selectedYearIndex))")
            Picker("Year", selection: $selectedYearIndex) {
                ForEach(years.indices) { yearIndex in
                    Text("\(self.yearString(at: yearIndex))")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct YearPicker_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        YearPicker(start: 2000, end: 2020)
    }
}
```

[image: YearPicker]

Comment: Thank you alot for the help I was just wondering isn't there a modifier for the Date picker to save the hassle.

Comment: @Z.Elshazly sadly there isn't. The built-in `DatePicker` can only display dates (with day/month/year format), times (in hour/minute/second format) or both. It cannot display individual date components. If you want to achieve that, you need to build a custom UI element.

Comment: Thanks anyway for the help I actually used your code just did a little adjustment :P .

Comment: @Z.Elshazly Glad I could help. If you found my answer useful, please consider accepting it. If you're unsure how to do that, you can read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).